# Eloquent work around for composite keys, creating new rows does not work but updating does

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables:

```
order_items
- product_id
- order_id
- qty_ordered

stock_movements
- product_id
- order_id
- qty_picked
```

Order items has the following relationship to stock movements:

```
return $this->hasMany(StockMovement::class, 'product_id', 'product_id')
            ->where('order_id', '=', $this->order_id);
```

This works fine for getting records and I can also increment existing rows like.

```
$this->stockMovement()->increment('picked', $int);
```

... however, using the create method, the order_id part of the relationship is missed out. I assume this is because its in the where statement and does not already exist. This does not work...

```
$this->stockMovement()->create(['picked' => $int]);
```

I realise that eloquent does not support composite keys but is there an elegant work around for this, short of building the query with the missing key manually. i.e.

```
$this->stockMovement()->create(['order_id' => $this->order_id, 'picked' => $int]);
```